# App icon with gloss effect on iTunes

Tags: ios, iphone, itunes, application-icon

Today i successfully release my new update to my app. Then i discover that my app icon on iTunes is without glossy effect, but not in iTunes website.

Why this icons are different ? I changed nothing inside my info.plist file or project settings

[image: Screen from web iTunes] [image: Screen from iTunes app]

Comment: I have a thread on the same issue here:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22445462/itunes-preview-has-started-showing-incorrect-icons-for-new-app-submissions-and-u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Apple didn't update the iTunes website properly. Your icon will be shown without the gloss on a device.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paper-stories-from-facebook/id794163692?mt=8 Here is an example for this glitch. New apps should not get the glossy effect - it's against the design guidelines of iOS 7.

Comment: my app support iOS 6 + , and icons shown on the device or simulator are without gloss. I think it will be fixed by Apple someday or with my new update )

Comment: I wouldn't choose this as the accepted answer because it is not a solution, but that is just me.

Comment: SuperFace, I've visited the example app link you've provided. Surprisingly, it doesn't have the gloss effect in iTunes preview, maybe they got it fixed or something. Interesting.

Comment: Yes, they've just fixed it. Not bad :)

Comment: My apps are still incorrectly showing the gloss effect. I guess I have no choice but to contact the monkeys over at Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has fixed the issue of glossy overlays showing up in iTunes preview. For the change to take effect, you simple have to submit an update to your app, once the update is approved, it will be fixed on iTunes preview.