# iTunes preview has started showing incorrect icons for new app submissions and updates

Tags: ios, iphone, icons, itunes, app-store-connect

I've noticed that as of a couple weeks ago, whenever I update one of my apps and it gets approved, it will start showing its icon with the glossy overlay in iTunes preview.

I have not changed a thing, it is not suppose to show the glossy overlay. In itunes connect I can see that the prerendered icon flag is set to true, which is correct. The icon is shown correctly everywhere (in-device, app store, iTunes) except for iTunes preview.

As a perfectionist I find this annoying.

**UPDATE:**

I tried setting the "Icon already includes gloss effects" (UIPrerenderedIcon) as YES to the app plist, which used to be the old way of letting them know you don't want the gloss effect. The app got approved, and it is still showing the gloss effect in iTunes preview. So this idea is ruled out as a potential solution.

Comment: I take it you're still deploying to iOS 6 and prior?

Comment: I'm deploying to iOS 6.0 and up. I have been doing that for much longer than the time this problem came into existence, so I don't think that has anything to do with it.

Comment: What's wrong with trying iOS 7 and up only to see if it corrects the issue?

Comment: Nothing. If someone had real evidence that submitting for iOS 7 and up causes this issue to be fixed, I would be content with that. However, I cannot afford to do that test on one of my apps, and I personally doubt that this is the solution to the problem. My guess is that the guys over at apple screwed something up in itunes preview, which would not be a surprise because I have seen them screw up little things like this in the past.

Comment: I wouldn't put that past them for the iTunes connect issues, as they clearly introduced more bugs in iOS 7.1 that didn't exist in 7.0

Comment: I disagree. In my observation they did not introduce more bugs in iOS 7.1. But I'm not here to argue that point (make a new thread for that). This issue had started before iOS 7.1 came out, and I have been able to submit for iOS 6.0 and up for 1 year without this issue.

Comment: My deployment target is iOS 7 and I see the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple has fixed this issue. You need to submit an update to any app that has this issue, and it will be fixed once the update is approved.